# Integral inequality $\int^{\pi}_{0} f^2(x)dx \le \int^{\pi}_{0} (f')^2(x)dx + (\int^{\pi}_{0} f(x)dx)^2$.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

Let $f \in H^1(0,\pi)$, show that $\int^{\pi}_{0} f^2(x)dx \le \int^{\pi}_{0} (f')^2(x)dx + (\int^{\pi}_{0} f(x)dx)^2$.

$H^1(0,\pi) = W^{1,2}(0,\pi)$, Sobolev space.
The question is from PDE course, but I guess it's true for all functions as long as integrals in the inequality are finite.

I tried IBP, Holder inequality, but cannot get the answer.
Would appreciate any suggestions where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Extend $f$ to an even function on $[-\pi, \pi]$ ans use Parseval's identity.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy How go from $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^2=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {\hat{f}}^2$ to the answer ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\int_0^\pi g^2\,dx \leq \int_0^\pi(g')^2\,dx +(\int_0^\pi g\,dx)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359203/show-that-int-0-pi-g2-dx-leq-int-0-pig2-dx-int-0-pi-g-dx2)

Comment: I guess yes.. sorry for duplicate question, but we did not study Parseval's identity, or  used Fourier in the class. So there should be another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked out your problem but it reminds me of Poincare type inequalities. Below is from Partial Differential Equations in Action by Salsa, and I have seen this called Poincare-Wirtinger inequality elsewhere:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain and $ E \subset \Omega$, with $|E|\gt 0$. If $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ let
$$ f_E = \frac{1}{|E|} \int_E f \,dx $$
and $ w = f-f_E $. Then $ \int_\Omega w =0$ and we get ( where $C\gt0$ )

$$ \| f - f_E\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$

Square both sides and expand the LHS and you should have all the terms you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That works!